ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'milvus_lite' on Windows
I encountered a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'milvus_lite' while running the following code after following the installation instructions.
I used the command pip install -U pymilvus and then tried to execute this code:
from pymilvus import MilvusClient


client = MilvusClient("./milvus_demo.db")

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I'm not sure why your answer was deleted, where you said the problem was that you were on Windows and the package is not supported there, just like @KerryJen just answered again, but I assume that's still simply the answer, right?

is Your system Windows?
Not supported yet.
https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-lite/blob/main/README.md


@kkakkurt It does actually answer the question.
